# Python requests equivalent of following curl code

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Could you please inform what would be Python requests equivalent of following curl code to upload file to knack? Specifically part after -F option. Thank you

```
curl -X POST "https://api.knack.com/v1/applications/YOUR-APP-ID/assets/file/upload" \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'x-knack-rest-api-key: YOUR-API-KEY' \
  -F "files=@/path/to/your/file.txt"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [requests api](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request) and the arguments you can supply to `requests.post`? (specifically the `headers` and `files` arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `requests.post` with [`files`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [`headers`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers). Your `curl` code is equivalent to:

```
url = "https://api.knack.com/v1/applications/YOUR-APP-ID/assets/file/upload"
files = {'files':open('/path/to/your/file.txt', 'rb')}
headers = {'x-knack-rest-api-key': 'YOUR-API-KEY'}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

When using the `files` argument, `requests` creates the necessary headers automatically so you don't need to have "Content-Type" or "Content-Length" in `headers`.